# How to migrate Mysql data to elasticsearch using logstash

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I need a brief explanation of how can I convert MySQL data to Elastic Search using logstash.
can anyone explain the step by step process about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a broad question, I don't know how much you familiar with `MySQL` and `ES`. Let's say you have a table `user`. you may just simply dump it as `csv` and load it at your `ES` will be good. but if you have a dynamic data, like the `MySQL` just like a pipeline, you need to write a `Script` to do those stuff. anyway you can check the below link to build your basic knowledge before you ask How.

[How to dump mysql?](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html)

[How to load data to ES](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/tutorial-load-dataset.html)

Also, since you probably want to know how to covert your `CSV` to json file, which is the best suite for ES to understand.

[How to covert CSV to JSON](https://www.idiotinside.com/2015/09/18/csv-json-pretty-print-python/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the [jdbc input plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html) for logstash.

[Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#_usage) is a config example.

Answer (score 0):

Let me provide you with a high level instruction set.

- Install Logstash, and Elasticsearch.
- In Logstash bin folder copy jar ojdbc7.jar.
- For logstash, create a config file ex: config.yml

```
# 
input {
    # Get the data from database, configure fields to get data incrementally
    jdbc {
        jdbc_driver_library => "./ojdbc7.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@db:1521:instance"
        jdbc_user => "user"
        jdbc_password => "pwd"

        id => "some_id"

        jdbc_validate_connection => true
        jdbc_validation_timeout => 1800
        connection_retry_attempts => 10
        connection_retry_attempts_wait_time => 10

        #fetch the db logs using logid
        statement => "select * from customer.table where logid > :sql_last_value order by logid asc"

        #limit how many results are pre-fetched at a time from the cursor into the client’s cache before retrieving more results from the result-set
        jdbc_fetch_size => 500
        jdbc_default_timezone => "America/New_York"

        use_column_value => true
        tracking_column => "logid"
        tracking_column_type => "numeric"
        record_last_run => true

        schedule => "*/2 * * * *"

        type => "log.customer.table"
        add_field => {"source" => "customer.table"}
        add_field => {"tags" => "customer.table" } 
        add_field => {"logLevel" => "ERROR" }

        last_run_metadata_path => "last_run_metadata_path_table.txt"
    }

}

# Massage the data to store in index
filter {
    if [type] == 'log.customer.table' {
        #assign values from db column to custom fields of index
        ruby{
            code => "event.set( 'errorid', event.get('ssoerrorid') );
                    event.set( 'msg', event.get('errormessage') );
                    event.set( 'logTimeStamp', event.get('date_created'));
                    event.set( '@timestamp', event.get('date_created'));
                    "
        }
        #remove the db columns that were mapped to custom fields of index
        mutate {
            remove_field => ["ssoerrorid","errormessage","date_created" ]
        }
    }#end of [type] == 'log.customer.table' 
} #end of filter

# Insert into index
output {
    if [type] == 'log.customer.table' {
        amazon_es {
            hosts => ["vpc-xxx-es-yyyyyyyyyyyy.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com"]
            region => "us-east-1"
            aws_access_key_id => '<access key>'
            aws_secret_access_key => '<secret password>'
            index => "production-logs-table-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        }
    }
}
```

- Go to bin, Run as 
  `logstash -f config.yml`